# Are there any parts of the 9th arrondissement in Paris that is known to be unsafe?

Tags: safety, paris, solo-travel, female-travellers

My friend is thinking of renting a place in the 9th.  As a single female who looks stereotypically lesbian for lack of a better way to say it… are there any issues in the 9th regarding women walking alone at midnight or would the above mentioned things draw any bad attention?

And, I'm not asking for subjective info before anybody points that out but things that every local knows to be generally bad area.

Comment: What would make you think it's safe/unsafe? Have you read anything anywhere?

Comment: You could look at crime statistics. If you can read some French, this [presentation](http://julienas.ipt.univ-paris8.fr/vgodard/pub/geomarke/memoires/07-08/boudiaf.pdf) might be interesting for you.

Answer (score 3):

There are two areas in the 9th Arrondissment that I know of as places to avoid...

The area between Boulevard de Clichy and Rue de Douai.  These two streets run parallel at the northern end of the 9th Arrondissment and they constitute part of the 'red light district' (although prostitution is illegal in Paris). There are lots of triple-X shops and clubs that attract the adventurous and lure them in to scams.  There are lots of transvestites roaming about along with straight prostitutes and this crowd attracts drug dealers and pickpockets.  I wouldn't even *think* about entering a club or restaurant in that area.  While I have taken tourists to the shows on Boulevard de Clichy and then night walks up to Montmartre, these areas are safer (large groups also make a difference).

The other area is on the eastern edge of the 9th Arrondissment in the vicinity of Gare du Nord.  Although the area is heavily patrolled by the police, it's still a no-go zone and likely to be especially dangerous at night.  I once saw a person get murdered there (a victim of an aborted robbery attempt), it was in the station itself so not in the 9th, but the whole area is volatile.  It's also a tinderbox for racial tensions.

On the other hand, the south side of the 9th is relatively peaceful and relatively safe.  It's generally safe from the Opera all the way up to the Lorette church.

You mentioned your friend's appearance is 'stereotypically lesbian'.  This may be a mitigating factor in the area around Pigalle, but not in the area near Gare du Nord.

Comment: Would "Rue de Dunkerque" fall under "safe" or "tensions"? Do mind telling me what the demographic of the 9th is? Students, middle-class etc. :-) So the station of Gare d Nord is safe at what hours?  Racial tensions are between which groups? Mitigatng factor as in being attacked being hassled or to buy services?

Comment: @verve , please edit your question to include these details.  Please see  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions or altneratively http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions

Comment: @verve, did you end up staying in the 9th? Do you have any useful information further to this question?